# Undefined variable error in class

Tags: php, mysql, function, class

I have a class that running inside a form to talk to a database, however the variables I'm using are returning errors. I have searched google but I cannot get a clear answer to my problem. Here are the errors, I've probably missed something obvious...hopefully:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: beer_name in /home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/models/beer.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined variable: beer_type in /home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/models/beer.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined variable: beer_abv in /home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/models/beer.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined variable: beer_rating in /home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/models/beer.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined variable: BeerEditor in /home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/forms/beeradded.php on line 38

Fatal error: Call to a member function addBeer() on a non-object in /home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/forms/beeradded.php on line 38
```

Here is my class:

```
protected $beer_name;   //varchar(45)
protected $beer_type;   //varchar(45)
protected $beer_abv;    //decimal(4,2) alcohol percentage ex. 06.50
protected $beer_rating; //char(10) 1 awful beer, 10 great beer


public function __construct($beer_name = null){
    if ($beer_name !== null){
        $this->setBeerName($beer_name);
    }    
    //defaults
    //$this->setBeerType($beer_type);
    //$this->setBeerABV($beer_abv);
    //$this->setBeerRating($beer_rating);


}

    public function setBeerName(){
        $this->beer_name = $beer_name;
    }
    public function getBeerName(){
            return $this->beer_name;
    }

    public function setBeerType(){
        $this->beer_type = $beer_type;
    }
    public function getBeerType(){
        return $this->beer_type;
    }

    public function setBeerABV(){
        $this->beer_abv = $beer_abv;
    }
    public function getBeerABV(){
        return $this->beer_abv;
    }

    public function setBeerRating(){
        $this->beer_rating = $beer_rating;
    }
    public function getBeerRating(){
        return $this->beer_rating;
    }
```

}

Here is my form:

```
<?php
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require "/home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/allincludes.php";

//var_dump($_POST);
if ($_SESSION['logged_in']!="yes"){
    header ("Location: unauth.php");
}



//if (count($_POST)>0){
//need to add in validation check here
//
//
//
//
//$validationErrors= 0;

    //if(count($validationErrors == 0 )){
        $form=$_POST;
        $beer_name = $form['beer_name'];
        $beer_type = $form['beer_type'];
        $beer_abv = $form['beer_abv'];
        $beer_rating = $form['beer_rating'];

   // }

    $new_beer = new Beer($beer_name);
    $new_beer->setBeerType($beer_type);
    $new_beer->setBeerABV($beer_abv);
    $new_beer->setBeerRating($beer_rating);

    $BeerEditor->addBeer($new_beer);

    echo "Beer added.";
 echo '<a href="addbeer.php"> Back to add menu </a>';  
//}
```

Comment: Variable scope: You're calling $this->setBeerName() with an argument, but the method needs to accept that argument. `public function setBeerName($beer_name){
        $this->beer_name = $beer_name;
    }`.... etc

Comment: @MarkBaker any idea what is causing the fatal error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget to pass the argument, here:

```
public function setBeerName(){
   $this->beer_name = $beer_name;
}
```

it should be:

```
public function setBeerName($beer_name){
   $this->beer_name = $beer_name;
}
```

please check in function setBeerType, setBeerABV, setBeerRating too.